# fetching image from external location in meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor

I am building a meteor app, that allows user to upload images. The images upload are stored in "/tmp/images/" directory in my local system.

How can I display the images from the above directory.
So far, I have seen displaying images only from "public" directory in meteor. But if I start adding images uploaded by the user in "public", then everytime the user uploads the image, the server will get refreshed.

So I would basically want to display images from "/tmp/images/" rather.

Any idea?

Comment: You can use nginx to display static assets :) https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-meteor-js-application-on-ubuntu-14-04-with-nginx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no other way to fetch images from another directories outside the project folder. That is the reason Meteor has built "public" directory for us. The path "/" itself indicates the beginning of project folder. Well if you are storing images in locations like amazon s3, then simply hitting the url in the  tag fetch the image.

So the bottom line is either u put ur images in public folder or store images in some outside location which can be fetched by simply hitting the image url.

And don't worry about refresh, it does not happen so in production mode. This only happens in development mode.

Answer (score 2):

I would advise you to store your images using gridFS:

1. you will be able to store files bigger than 16Mb.
2. the files will not "touch" your server, they are directly piped into your database.
3. you can handle them afterwards like a collection, so you can allow/deny access to it as you see fit.

The only place designed in meteor to store static assets is the `public` folder. You shouldn't try to put these elsewhere.

If you want to give a try to gridFS, you can use the [file-collection package](https://github.com/vsivsi/meteor-file-collection). It is quick and easy to setup.

Alternatively, as advised by @Marius Darila, you can [use Nginx to serve static content](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-meteor-js-application-on-ubuntu-14-04-with-nginx)

As answered by @Michel Floyd, you can also use [collectionFS](https://github.com/CollectionFS/Meteor-CollectionFS), but, to quote the [file-collection package](https://github.com/vsivsi/meteor-file-collection) author:

> Here's the difference in a nutshell: collectionFS is a Ferrari, and
>   file-collection is a Fiat.
>
> They do approximately the same thing using some of the same
>   technologies, but reflect different design priorities. file-collection
>   is much simpler and somewhat less flexible; but if it meets your needs
>   you'll find it has a lot fewer moving parts and may be significantly
>   more efficient to work with and use.

Comment: but why does the application refresh when the user uploads file in the 'public' folder? That should not happen rite?

Comment: You are in development mode, not production. This is why. Here is a discussion about this particular feature: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/894

Comment: Ok. I cannot use the "gridFS" package, because I am not using any Mongo.Collection in the client to prevent polling. So for every MongoCollection.find(), I am calling a method in the server. And if I store the images in the public folder, I am not being able to fetch them if I commit the project in git and use it in production

Comment: If you're trying to "prevent polling" then you don't understand Meteor. Meteor uses websockets to synchronize data between the server and the client. Websockets allows the server to push new data to the client without polling. You can see for yourself by opening the network tab in your inspector and watching the traffic.

Comment: +1 to @Michel  Floyd. Two other things: 1) gridFS isn't a package, it is a mongo feature allowing to store big documents (more than 16mb). 2) I guess that you mainly use methods because you don't want the user to mess with your collections from console. Consider that it can be quite fine tuned in the native driver allow/deny functions. If you can't do it there, do it in a method. The solution I advised will use a special collection you could call "file". You can secure it as you want, and it does not mean you need to give up using your other methods.

Comment: @user4523328 concerning the page refresh, re-read my first comment

Comment: While gridFS may be a mongo feature, there are many packages available for taking advantage of it: https://atmospherejs.com/?q=gridfs. Using methods does not prevent the user from messing with your collections from the console. Your method calls are easily findable even in uglyfied javascript and can be called directly by the user with a little bit of reverse engineering/logical deduction. There is no practical security difference between `MyCollection.insert({content: myContent})` and `Meteor.call('insertIntoMyCollection',myContent)`

Comment: I disagree regarding methods vs allow/deny. You can safely `check()` every method argument object field & structure in methods and make sure that no extra field is inserted *depending on the type of task you want to achieve*. You can also include several other inserts (in other collections) in a method or add fields you will never expose. I am quite interested in this talk. You are welcome to convince me on chat & learn me new stuff if you want to.

Comment: I have a blog post pending on this specific subject, I'll let you know when I publish it. Yes, your method can be extra secure assuming you write it carefully but you can't protect it being invoked from console or malicious code. OTOH if you write your method poorly you are bypassing allow/deny rules. See http://0rocketscience.blogspot.com/2015/07/meteor-security-no-2-all-praise-aldeed.html for a post on how to use collection2 to secure collection changes.

Comment: nice link thank you. Aldeed deserves the praise. I agree with the importance of writing the method correctly. I also agree that you can't protect it from being invoked from console or malicious code. Client side validation (collection2) doesn't hurt either. I would be glad to read your article when you will publish it. One idea maybe for the article (one of my blind spots): (how) can we write methods in `both` folder to keep latency compensation benefits while ensuring that server will have he last word? I tried it only once, quickly, with no success.

Answer (score 2):

You should also look at [CollectionFS](https://atmospherejs.com/packages/collectionFS). This will let you use different storage adapters as your needs evolve without changing your code. It's a very well done and robust package.